# MVC controller and view relationship

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, view, controller

First off, I've done a lot of research on the web (including this site) and have found lots of conflicting information on how the model and controller communicate in an MVC pattern. Here is my specific question (I'm using AS3), but it's a general MVC question...

I have two main components... a list of recipes and a form that displays a selected recipe. The form has an edit state that allows you to edit the recipe and then save or cancel the changes. What is the best way (using MVC principles) to handle changes made to a recipe? So far, I have the save button trigger an event which is captured by the controller.

Should I have the save button (the view) pass an object with the current state of the fields along with the event (some logic in view)? Should I allow the controller to hold access to the view and have the controller figure out what's in the fields on its own (added coupling)? Should events be made every time a field in the form is changed and the controller keeps track of the state of each field (lots of events)? Or is their another way? Note: I don't want to bind the fields to the model because I only want the data to save if the save button is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I have the save button (the view) pass an object with the
>   current state of the fields along with the event (some logic in view)?

yes, this is not 'logic in the view', it does not decide anything, simply reporting an action and its current state

> Should I allow the controller to hold access to the view and have the
>   controller figure out what's in the fields on its own (added
>   coupling)?

no, this would become very messy, pass a VO with the event

> Should events be made every time a field in the form is changed and
>   the controller keeps track of the state of each field (lots of
>   events)?

is an option, but this basically is the same as hitting the save button, the trigger is different (TextField.onChange), but you can dispatch the same event (setup is form = view, dispatches one general event with a VO, not an event for each field)

> Or is their another way?

MVC flow w/ events:

1. onClick save btn: a RecipeEvent.SAVE is dispatched (from the view), with a VO (value object) containing the Recipe data (e.g. RecipeVO)
2. the controller catches this, and as the controller is where the logic resides, it decides what to do with it: update the RecipesModel (either directly by calling a method on the model, or by a custom event e.g. RecipeModelEvent.SAVE)
3. the model stores the data, and dispatches the RecipeEvent.UPDATE event (with the RecipeVO)

   - the views updated itself accordingly (check if the RecipeVO.ID is same, update data representation e.g. title…)
   - optionally, a controller could save the data to a back-end/remote database

As for the event listeners: views listen to the model, controller listen to the views.

About de-coupling: 
use interfaces (by using an IModel you can swap out the model easily by another implementation, as you register the event listeners against the interface instead of the actual implementation)

Obviously, all this results in a lot of registering/removing event listeners, and keeping reference to the models/views/controllers to be able to register to the appropriate instance. An alternative is to use a framework as RobotLegs, as it makes a central event-bus available + easy/automatic cleanup of event listeners in the mediator class of a view.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is really a database question. what I would do is create a stored procedure that first checks to see if the recipe already exists. If yes then update it. If not then add a new recipe. (you'll have to bind your entity to a stored procedure. other MVC frameworks can do this. I don't know about actionscript)

if that's not an option then I guess you would have to cache the original form in a helper class in the controller and then compare it to what the user is trying to save. And have the controller decide whether to update the recipe.

I think it's much cleaner to use the first way, but I've never used actionscript so...

Answer (score 0):

Colin Moock's lecture on MVC in ActionScript is quite old, but still one of the best explications: http://www.moock.org/lectures/mvc/

Your model should populate your view, and your view should send input events to the controller, which should decide what to do with the input. As g10 says, wait until the save button is clicked and then pass an object with the modified fields up to the controller for processing. The controller can then decide whether or not to accept it, and whether to update an existing model object or create a new one.

Comment: I looked at Mook's site before posting this question. He suggests that the view would pass an event to the controller which would change the model (if the controller decides to). But, he also says: "in some cases, the controller modifies the view directly and does not update the model at all" Wasn't sure if passing back the field data from the view would be considered logic or not or if I should grab it directly using the controller. Sounds like you and g10 are both saying that passing the data back in the event from the view to the controller is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: I can think of quite a few instances where I'd want to update the view from the controller without changing the model, but then I'm not a purist when it comes to MVC, and might even put some logic into the view. Take an order form with fields for billing and shipping addresses, and a checkbox saying that they are the same address, and only display the shipping fields if the user unchecks the box. The logic for that doesn't need a consultation of the model, but should it be in the V, or the C? That's a judgement call - where might you reuse the code, where is it easiest to maintain?